# Getting mouse co-ordinates on a mouse click in C#

Tags: c#, logging, mouse, coordinates

I want to build myself an application that will run in the background (system tray) and log the co-ordinates of my mouse whenever I click the left or right buttons. I found this code online to get the mouse co-ordinates through an event that triggers:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mouseEv) 
{ 
    txtMouseX.Text = mouseEv.X.ToString(); 
    txtMouseY.Text = mouseEv.Y.ToString(); 
}
```

This points me in the right direction, I now know how I can get the X and Y co-ordinates of the mouse, but I don't know how to trigger a function or whatever on a mouse click if the application is running in the background. Also, it seems that this code only works in the form it is running in, not for the entire screen?

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: How to get the mouse coordinates depends on whether you're using Windows Forms or WPF. Which are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a global hook.  Here is a code project article with a library that does what you are looking for:  [Global Mouse and Keyboard Library](http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalmousekeyboardlib.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetCursorPos win32 API to get the position of your Mouse at any time. Here is the sample code for this:-

```
Dim MyPointAPI As POINTAPI
```

Private Type POINTAPI
  X As Long
  Y As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Public Sub Timer1_Timer()
  l = GetCursorPos(MyPointAPI)
  Label1.Caption = CStr(MyPointAPI.X) & ", " & CStr(MyPointAPI.Y)
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/.
It allows you to track mouse coordinate system wide even if your application is inactive (in tray).